# openSSL certificate-verification on Linux

Tags: openssl

JKJS

I have this chain of certificates:
        rcert.pem(self-signed)    -->scert.pem    -->ccert.pem

All three certificates are generated by me.No internet connection is used anywhere.This is perfect offline work.
Now,below are some commands and their output:

```
hari@harikrishna:~/hari$ openssl verify rcert.pem
rcert.pem: C = IN, ST = OM, L = OM, O = HARI, OU = HARI, CN = OM, emailAddress = OM
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
hari@harikrishna:~/hari$ openssl verify -CAfile rcert.pem scert.pem
scert.pem: OK
hari@harikrishna:~/hari$ openssl verify -CAfile rcert.pem rcert.pem
rcert.pem: OK
hari@harikrishna:~/hari$ openssl verify -CAfile rcert.pem -untrusted scert.pem ccert.pem
ccert.pem: C = IN, ST = HARI, L = HARI, O = HARI, OU = HARI, CN = HARI, emailAddress = HARI
error 24 at 1 depth lookup:invalid CA certificate
OK
```

Why is error 24 created.How to remove it?Is it something like trusted or untrusted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JKJS

Got answer of my own question:

1)Created root CA certificate by these commands:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -keyout rootkey.pem -out rootreq.pem

openssl x509 -req -in rootreq.pem -sha1 -signkey rootkey.pem -out rootcert.pem
```

2)Installed CA certificate as trusted certificate by following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra

sudo cp rootcert.pem /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/rootcert.crt

sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates

sudo update-ca-certificates
```

3)Created intermediate certificate signed by root CA by following commands:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -keyout skey.pem -out sreq.pem

sudo openssl x509 -req -in sreq.pem -sha1 -CA /etc/ssl/certs/rootcert.pem -CAkey rootkey.pem -CAcreateserial -out scert.pem
```

4)Created client certificate signed by intermediate CA by following commands:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -keyout ckey.pem -out creq.pem

openssl x509 -req -in creq.pem -sha1 -CA scert.pem -CAkey skey.pem -CAcreateserial -out ccert.pem
```

Now, Chain Of Trust is working fine:

1)verification of root CA

```
openssl verify rootcert.pem 
rootcert.pem: OK
```

2)verification of intermediate CA

```
openssl verify scert.pem 
scert.pem: OK
```

3)verification of client certificate

```
openssl verify -CAfile scert.pem ccert.pem
ccert.pem: OK
```

Comment: Well done on finding the solution. A nice and complete mini-tutorial.
Small remark for those finding this now, change it to 2048 bytes and sha256 since these are more common these days.

Comment: Warning, the certificate chain verification commands above are more permissive that you might expect! By default, in addition to checking the given CAfile, they also check for any matching CAs in the system's certs directory e.g. /etc/ssl/certs. To prevent this behavior and make sure you're checking against your particular CA cert, also pass a -CApath option with a non-existant directory, e.g.: "openssl verify -CApath nosuchdir -CAfile scert.pem ccert.pem"

Comment: this is very cool, does work on linux. but how do i install root cert on mac??