# How to validate .crt file using trusted CA Certificate using openssl in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

I am having client Certificate "A" AND i have CA1 certificate As Root certificate.

Now I have to validate Certificate A is trusted or not by using CA1 certificate (trusted )

Is it possible to do this validation ?

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]

                      pathForResource:@"CA" ofType:@"crt"];

NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]

                     initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;                 // 1



SecCertificateRef myCert;

myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData);    // 2



SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();         // 3



SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };

CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(

                                   NULL, (void *)certArray,

                                   1, NULL);

SecTrustRef myTrust;

OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(

                                                myCerts,

                                                myPolicy,

                                                &myTrust);  // 4



SecTrustResultType trustResult;

if (status == noErr) {

    status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);       // 5

}
```

//...                                                             // 6

```
if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {

    // ...;

}
```

// ...

```
if (myPolicy)

    CFRelease(myPolicy);
```

but i am getting  SecCertificateCreateWithData null and getting crash

Comment: take a look this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218055/how-to-validate-a-client-certificate-using-the-trusted-internediate-ca-certifica and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295585/openssl-certificate-verification-on-linux

Comment: @NitinGohel i am getting crash, Please check my update